# Best way to make a child object observable with knockout?

Tags: knockout.js

What's the best way to make a child/grandchild object observable with knockout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked into the [knockout mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html), it can automatically convert JS/JSON into observables, all the way down a chain.